# how can i solve an error that "cd: can't cd to /data/data/package_name/databases"

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-emulator

Hello guys i need your help.I am working on project that can store a record of incoming messages using sqlite but when i tried to open my sqlite database it gives me such error . Please help me
..[image]

Comment: I think you cannot open database on device but you can open db of an emulator its for security reasons

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the file on a real device you have to do:

```
>adb shell
>run-as com.deepak.report
```

and then,

```
> cd databases
```

But sqlite3 is not available on real devices, you should use emulators.

Comment: i have tried it but when i give command to cd databases it the o/p is cd: cant cd to databases....now what should i do @Zoubiock

Comment: what is the output when you make >ls

Comment: "ls" is a command that list elements in the directory. what did it tell you ?

Comment: By the way, it's "LS", not "IS"

Comment: then it give me o/p that no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

if u r using eclipse u can download this plugin just a copy paste of a .jar file
Just go through 
this [Link](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/) follow instructions and see database in emulator DDMS of Eclipse.

Normally Database stored in `//data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>` folder of the Android Device.